# Nivo Slider, showing image one on top of the other (nothing of "sliding")

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nivo-slider

I'm trying to set up Nivo Slider in a rails app with twitter-bootstrap, the problem I'm facing is tha images appear on top of the other not sliding, any idea how to solve this?

here is my code:

load the nivo slider:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <% @page.images.each_with_index do |img, index| %>      
            <%= image_tag img.url, :title => '#htmlcaption' %> 
      </div>
</div>
    <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <%=raw @page.caption_for_image_index(index) %>
  </div>  
    <% end %>
```

_javascript.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.nivo.slider.pack' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.nivo.slider' %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade',
        pauseTime: 5000,
        directionNav:true,
        controlNav:true

    });
});
</script>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from the `each` loop. If you notice inside the loop you have two closing `div` tags - just bellow this line `<%= image_tag img.url, :title => '#htmlcaption' %>`. Therefore you open the `divs` once, but close then multiple times.

What you can do instead is change slightly the code like:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
  <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <% @page.images.each do |img| %>      
        <%= image_tag img.url, :title => img.caption_for_image %> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a look at [Nivo Docs](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation). There are further example for alternative caption options.

Comment: Hi @bborisovs, thank you for your answer however when I implement it I get a "undefined method img.caption_for_image" error, any idea why?

Comment: What is the `column name` where the caption is stored. This example states that the name of the column is `caption_for_image`.

Comment: the name of the column is 'caption' but I already tried and get the same error.

Comment: I assume both `url` and `caption` are stored in the same table e.g. `@page = Model.all`; and both are accessible from within the Model e.g. `attr_accessible :url, :caption`. So try `@page.each` and `img.caption` only.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy fix to this issue:

I'm using a legacy CMS and that's inserting image map tags next to some images in the slider (resulting in blank slides). Simply ignoring irrelevant elements seems to work well.

In your `jquery.nivo.slider.js` file replace line 36
//Find our slider children

Replace this

```
36 - var kids = slider.children();
```

with

```
36 - var kids = slider.children("img,a");
```

save the change, reload your browser and issue solved.

For more details visit [github gilbitron / Nivo-Slider](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/pull/206)